# How to get all product in the woo-commerce?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, password

I want to get all the product data in the WooCommerce (sku, name, price, stock count, availability and etc.). Can I do that using `WP_Query`?

Comment: Please, have a look to this recent related thread : [How to get all product in the WooCommerce programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380749/how-to-get-all-product-in-the-woocommerce-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, `WP_Query` fetches posts, it doesn't display them. You can query for WooCommerce products as they're a custom post type. Just create a query object, and specify the `post_type` parameter to use the post type WooCommerce uses, then loop over them, displaying them and grabbing the post meta such as the SKU as you go along.

How you would do that, and what post meta is used to store SKU price etc though is WooCommerce specific and beyond the scope of this site. Consult the WooCommerce documentation for those details

Comment: How to do it without  WP_Query?

Comment: @melvin all APIs that fetch posts use `WP_Query` internally. There is no API that both fetches the information, AND displays it